# Onclick not repeating with button (variable maxes out at an integer of 1)

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following javascript code, with the first two functions and the qty in the first variable towards the bottom being the most important here:

```
// show qty and price
function add(qty) {
qty++;
document.getElementById("qty").innerHTML = (qty);
}
function remove(qty) {
if (qty > 0) {
qty--;
document.getElementById("qty").innerHTML = (qty);
} else {
document.getElementById("qty").innerHTML = (qty);
}
}
// load products on home
function bl() {
document.getElementById("bl").style.display = "initial";
document.getElementById("br").style.display = "none";
}
function br() {
document.getElementById("br").style.display = "initial";
document.getElementById("bl").style.display = "none";
}
// load cart
function cart() {
document.getElementById("cart").style.display="block";
if (qty == 0) {
document.getElementById("by").style.display="none";
} else {
document.getElementById("by").style.display="block";
}
}
// leave cart
function leavecart() {
document.getElementById("cart").style.display="none";
}
// product list
var flower = {
 blueyellow: { 
    color : "linear-gradient(to right, blue, yellow)",
    src : "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/07/22/15/11/woman-7338352_1280.jpg",
    price : 30,
    qty : 0,
    size : "small"
  },
 redyellow: { 
    color : "red, yellow",
    src : "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/05/22/16/50/outdoors-7213961_1280.jpg",
    price : 25,
    qty : 0,
    size : "large"
  }
};
// product list in cart
document.getElementById("bycolor").style.display = (flower.blueyellow.color);
document.getElementById("bysrc").src = (flower.blueyellow.src);
document.getElementById("byprice").innerHTML = ("$" + flower.blueyellow.price);
```

Then I have two buttons: one to add to qty and one to remove from qty:

```
<div id="wrap" style="padding: 10px;">
<h2>Add to Cart</h2><p id="qty"></p><button onclick="add(flower.blueyellow.qty)">+</button><button onclick="remove(flower.blueyellow.qty)">-</button>
</div>
```

The problem here is that onclick only brings the qty to 1 and no further. I had it working before trying to adapt it to a variable within a variable, but now it stops.

Comment: Replace ```qty++``` with ```qty = qty + 1``` and see if that works. I think the ++ operator doesn't work on object values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are not increasing the actual value of flower.blueyellow.qty

```js
function add(color) {
  flower[color].qty++
    document.getElementById("qty").innerHTML=flower[color].qty;
}
function remove(color) {
  if (flower[color].qty > 0) {
  flower[color].qty--
  document.getElementById("qty").innerHTML = flower[color].qty;
  } else {
  document.getElementById("qty").innerHTML = flower[color].qty;
  }
}

var flower = {
 blueyellow: { 
    color : "linear-gradient(to right, blue, yellow)",
    src : "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/07/22/15/11/woman-7338352_1280.jpg",
    price : 30,
    qty : 0,
    size : "small"
  },
};
```

```html
<div id="wrap" style="padding: 10px;">
<h2>Add to Cart</h2><p id="qty"></p><button onclick="add('blueyellow')">+</button><button onclick="remove('blueyellow')">-</button>
</div>
```